# Regular Topological Infinite Spaces

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

Can anyone prove this please?

Let $Y$ be regular and $A\subset Y$ any infinite subset. Then there exists a family $\{U_n| n \geq 0\}$ of open sets whose closures are pairwise disjoint and such that $A\cap U_n \neq \emptyset$ for each $n\geq1$.

This is a theorem from James Dugundjis's book of Topology, he has a proof but I can't quite understand it.

His definition of regular spaces is as follows:

A Hausdorff space is regular if each $y\in Y$ and closed set A not containing y have disjoint neighborhoods.

I hope this will be answered. Thanks

Comment: At which precise point did you get stuck in the proof?

Comment: After the base case, I can't grasp his point in the proof.